# External CLK in Artix-7

Tags: fpga, clock, artix-series-fpga

I try to design a board with an ARTIX-7 FPGA. There is a big question that which pin of FPGA should I put an oscillator? 
I inspected a document about clocking the 7 series xilinx FPGA ([7 Series FPGAs
Clocking Resources](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug472_7Series_Clocking.pdf)
) but I still don't know what should I do, because I saw a design of a kintex-7 and is had been put various oscillator with different frequancy.

What is the difference between MRCC and SRCC pins?

I'm thankful if someone can help me!

Answer (score 2):

You can drive a clock into any CC (clock-capable) pin and use it as a GCLK or feed to a PLL or MMCM block.

There are special uses for some clocks, for example to implement memory interfaces, that have local low-skew local distribution in addition to driving a global net. That’s where MRCC and SRCC come in. MRCC inputs are Multi-region. SRCC are single-region.

The diagrams in the doc you linked explains SRCC and MRCC in more detail: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug472_7Series_Clocking.pdf#G4.319704